# How to get Kendo grid to color currency

Tags: javascript, css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I would like all negative values in this grid columns field to be displayed as red, and all positive values as green.  This code is for the columns object array:

```
{ field: "Amount", title: "Balance", format: "{0:c}", attributes: { style: "text-align: right;" }, template: "<font class='#if(Amount < 0) {# negative_field #} else {# positive_field #}'></font>" },
```

CSS

```
.negative_field {
    color: red;
}

.positive_field {
    color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your template:

```
template: "<font class='#if(Amount < 0) {# negative_field #} else {# positive_field #}'></font>"
                                                        Hash(#) should be closes here ^
```

And inside your `font` tag you should display your property:

```
<font...>#= Acount #</font>
```

But, instead of using `font`, use a `div` and remove the `format` property from your column to use [`kendo.toString(Acount, 'c')`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo#methods-toString) inside your template:

```
template: "<div class='currency # if(Amount < 0) {#negative_field# } else { #positive_field# } #'>#=kendo.toString(Amount, 'c') #</div>"
```

You can also remove `attributes` from your column and use just css:

```
.currency {
  text-align: right;
}
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/IbEyoZ)

Comment: thank you; here's another way Telerik told me to do it: http://dojo.telerik.com/iSAMO

Comment: @xinthose great! Almost the same thing I've proposed. Don't forget to mark the better answer here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You do it like so:

Kendo grid `columns`:

```
{ field: "Amount", title: "Balance", attributes: { style: "text-align: right;" }, template: function (e) { return format_currency(e, "Amount"); } },
```

Javascript:

```
var currency = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'USD',
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
});

function format_currency(e, property) {
    if (e[property] < 0) {
        return "<span class='negative_field'>" + currency.format(e[property]) + "</span>";
    }
    else if (e[property] === 0) {
        return "<span class='include_spaces'>$    -    </span>";
     }
     else {
        return "<span class='positive_field'>" + currency.format(e[property]) + "</span>";
    }
};
```

CSS:

```
.negative_field {
    color: red;
}
.positive_field {
    color: green;
}
.include_spaces {
    white-space: pre;
}
```